# Javascript function: how to reference the element that calls the function - and extract that element's value

Tags: javascript, function, getelementbyid, this

I am trying to make a table with a button for each row, each button I want to have it copy and paste the value of the button itself to the desired field.
my problem is I don't get texttocopy to be the `<input button value="">`

```
copypaste(id) {
   var texttocopy = document.getElementById(this);
   var wheretocopy = document.getElementById(id);
   wheretocopy.value = texttocopy.value;
}
```

I've tried a few other variations on this, and looking up the syntax has been unfruitful.

```
function copypaste(id) {
   var texttocopy = this;
   var wheretocopy = document.getElementById(id);
   wheretocopy.value = texttocopy.value;
}
```

`texttocopy` is the value of whatever calls the function.

the html is inside php so that's the reason for the . connectors and the switching of " and '.

where the button is:
    `php
    echo '<input TYPE="BUTTON" id="barcodebutton" value ="'.$row['barcode1'].'" onclick="copypaste('."'primaryRFID'".');">'`

field to input data into:
    `html
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" id="primaryRFID" NAME="primaryRFID">`

the expected result is the input of primaryRFID becomes the value of the button pressed.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function from inside an `onclick` attribute, the function is called without any `this` binding. However, `this` *is* bound while executing the `onclick` code itself, so you can just pass that as a regular argument:

```
onclick="copypaste(this, '."'primaryRFID'".');"
```

So now get that argument value via the function parameters:

```
function copypaste(texttocopy, id) {
   var wheretocopy = document.getElementById(id);
   wheretocopy.value = texttocopy.value;
}
```